# Handling file uploads with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am a bit overstrained with handling file uploads using multer. What I want to do is:

1. Uploading one or multiple files via ajax
2. Storing these files at a dynamic destination folder
3. Processing the contents files with a specific format (.json/.xml/.txt)

1) is already done and I managed storing these files inside of a tmp folder.
2) As far as I understood I need to store these files first and then move them to my desired location (which is a dynamic location)
3) I want to parse the files if possible, otherwise the files should just be stored as asset.

**My questions:**

1. How can I store (or move) the files at a dynamic target?
2. How can I process the file contents (for example to store the parsed contents in a database)?

**My code:**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        fs.mkdirsSync(config.fileHandler.uploadTempDir)
        cb(null, config.fileHandler.uploadTempDir)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
var stringsUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'sourceStrings[]', maxCount: 8 }])
router.post('/:projectId/update/sourcestrings', isLoggedIn, stringsUpload, processSourceStrings)
function processSourceStrings(req, res, next) {
    var projectId = req.params.projectId

    Project.findOne({ project_id: projectId }).populate('owner').then(function (project) {
        if (!project)
            return res.send(404, { error: "Couldn't find a project with this id" })

        if (!isAllowedToEditProject(req, project))
            return res.send(403, { error: "You are not allowed to edit this project" })

        // Move files to the right destination
        var targetpath = 'user/1/project/4/'

        // Process file

        return res.status(200).send()
    })
}
```

Comment: It seems you're missing the bit about what part(s) of your code aren't working the way you expect. Also, it seems the line of code where `upload` is defined is missing.

Comment: @mscdex you are right, I've added them. Well in my case so far it's working fine but I have no idea how I do process files and how do I move the files when they have been uploaded. Is there a way to process the uploaded files immediately or do I need to read the saved files afterwards? It's the very first time I am working with file uploads